# SQL query to copy field values into same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (post_order) structured like so:

```
   | post_id | term_id | post_type | taxonomy |
   |    1    |    6    |    post   | category |
   |    2    |    6    |    post   | category |
   |    3    |    6    |    post   | category |
```

I'd like to copy all of the fields to the same table, but change the term_id (say, for example, 7) so, the table would end up looking like this:

```
   | post_id | term_id | post_type | taxonomy |
   |    1    |    6    |    post   | category |
   |    2    |    6    |    post   | category |
   |    3    |    6    |    post   | category |
   |    1    |    7    |    post   | category |
   |    2    |    7    |    post   | category |
   |    3    |    7    |    post   | category |
```

I know I could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO post_order (post_id, term_id, post_type, taxonomy)
SELECT post_id, term_id, post_type, taxonomy
FROM post_order
WHERE term_id = 6
```

But this would make an exact duplicate and not change the term_id.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hard code the `term_id` to 7 in your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO post_order (post_id, term_id, post_type, taxonomy)
SELECT post_id, 7, post_type, taxonomy
FROM post_order
WHERE term_id = 6
```